# Using a datalist in a form in Spring-MVC

Tags: spring-mvc, html-datalist

I'm attempting to convert an input form from a  to  a  but  does not accept the list attribute, does anyone know a workaround? This is my first time using Spring and I'm at a loss here.

```
<tr>
        <th><form:label path="livrable.composant"><s:message code="composant"/></form:label></th>
        <td>
            <form:input path="livrables.composants" list="composants">
            <c:if test = "${not empty composants}">
                <datalist id="composants">
                    <c:forEach var="composantValue" items="${composants}">
                        <option value="${composantValue.nom}"/>
                    </c:forEach>
                </datalist>
            </c:if>
            <br/>
            <form:errors path="livrable.composant" cssClass="error"/>
        </td></tr>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind I'm an idiot, I didn't close the tag it should be:

```
<form:input path="livrables.composants" list="composants"/>
```